# Can not copy some SQL server files

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have attached a few databases to my sql server instance.  I wonder about the different behavious, while DBs have been attached the same way.

When I try to copy the folder that contains the files, some files do not copy and give error that file is in use, while some other, attached to the same instance and in the same folder, copy without any problem.
Please advise what is the difference?

Thanks

Comment: Which files copied and which didn't? System DBs would always be in use but user DBs might not.

Comment: not system DBs, my own DBs that i created sometimes ago in VS2008

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to copy the files are as follows, this only applies to user databases:

To move a data or log file as part of a planned relocation, follow these steps:

1. Run the following statement.
2. `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET OFFLINE;`
3. Move the file or files to the new location.
4. For each file moved, run the following statement.
5. `ALTER DATABASE database_name MODIFY FILE ( NAME = logical_name, FILENAME = 'new_path\os_file_name' );`
6. Run the following statement.
7. `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET ONLINE;`
8. Verify the file change by running the following query.
9. `SELECT name, physical_name AS CurrentLocation, state_desc FROM sys.master_files`